# Showing equivalence relation and class for a square

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Writing $I=\left [ 0,1 \right ]$ and $I^{2}=\left \{ \left ( x,y \right ):x,y \in I \right \}$,

define for $x,y \in I$

- $\left ( x,y \right )\sim \left ( x,y \right )$
- $\left ( 0,y \right )\sim \left ( 1,y \right )\sim \left ( 0,y \right )$
- $\left ( x,0 \right )\sim \left ( x,1 \right )\sim \left ( x,0 \right )$
- $\left ( 0,0 \right ) \sim \left ( 1,1 \right ),\left ( 1,1 \right )\sim \left ( 0,0 \right ),\left ( 1,0 \right ) \sim \left ( 0,1 \right ),\left ( 0,1 \right )\sim \left ( 1,0 \right )$

> Question:
>   Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation and give a geometrical representation of the set $I^{2}/\sim$ of equivalence class.

I have an idea of what is going on geometrically but I do not quite understand how I should go about determining the equivalence relation in this question.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must show that $\sim$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. Which of these are you stuck on and what have you tried?

Comment: I know I must show he 3 properties. That's the definition of equivalence relation. What I meant was I don't quite understand what the question wants and how I can use the given information to determine the equivalence relation holds.

Comment: Isn't the problem just to prove that the relation is an equivalence relation (you said you understand he geometric interpretation, so I leave that aside)? If you know the definition of an equivalence relation, then what part of the question do you not understand?